# Is there a language that allows for multiple sets of parentheses for one method?

Tags: language-agnostic

All languages I've seen so far expect method parameters to be declared inside one set of round brackets and the end of the method name.

```
addLineToFile(line,file)
```

I'm wondering which languages out there support splitting the method name and the parameters in multiple sets of round brackets. Or if there's a reason such thing does not exist.

e.g.

```
addLine(line)toFile(file)
```

Comment: [Objective-C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C) certainly has that: `[myColor changeColorToRed:5.0 green:2.0 blue:6.0]`

Comment: There are plenty of languages that do not use parentheses around function arguments (eg.  the CAML family of functional languages including F#).

Comment: You may also somewhat count languages which support call-time named arguments to provide a similar benefit to readability, e.g. Python: `myColor.changeTo(red=5.0,  green=2.0, blue=6.0)`

Comment: To expand on that, in such languages a call like `func a b c`, is really a function taking one argument returning a function taking one argument returning a function taking one argument which returns the result (this is known as Currying).

Comment: With the slight variation - `addLine(line).toFile(file)` this just looks like a fluent interface - you can find those implemented in all kinds of places, and they're not really *language* features in such a case.

Comment: In Smalltalk your example `addLineToFile(line, file)` could be written as `file addLine: line`.